# can't I change the python version of conda

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using some bioinformatics software that requires a python2 environment. I use conda to create a new environment and specify the python version as 2.7.18, but when I type 'python' I find that the python version is 3.9.5. I use the 'which python'code, and ls -l the link, and get return

`lrwxrwxrwx 1 leelee leelee 9 9月  22 20:06 /home/leelee/miniconda3/envs/clear2/bin/python -> python2.7`

I type 'python2.7' and got the version I wanted. But it is still 3.9.5 when type 'python'. I am very confused about this, how can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

using code below to check what env you have

`conda env list`

and you will get a list of env you create
then
using

`conda activate env_name`

to activate and get in the env

then you can use the python version you want.

if you can't get the python path you want by using

`which python`

when you are in an env

you need to edit your bash/zsh file to check that is there a python default path setting there.